# checking if json value is empty

Tags: python, json

I tried all the methods I found on SO but none is working for me

The JSON in question (trimmed)

```
json_data = requests.post(api_url, self.build_payload().json()

{
   "gmetadata":[
      {
         "title_jpn":"",
      }
   ]
}
```

The string is output of `curl -POST http://api.example.com`

This is my method:

```
# TODO: (core) Don't print empty string for japanese title if none given
@staticmethod
def build_title_jpn_string(json_data):
    if 'title_jpn' in json_data['gmetadata'][0] is not "":
        return 'Japanese Title: ' + pprint.pformat(json_data['gmetadata'][0]['title_jpn'])
```

I do not want it to execute when ['gmetadata'][0]['title_jpn'] is None.

I tried mutliple variations

```
    if 'title_jpn' in json_data['gmetadata'][0] is not "":
        return 'Japanese Title: ' + pprint.pformat(json_data['gmetadata'][0]['title_jpn'])
```

aswell as

```
    if 'title_jpn' in json_data['gmetadata'][0] is not None:
        return 'Japanese Title: ' + pprint.pformat(json_data['gmetadata'][0]['title_jpn'])

    if json_data['gmetadata'][0]['title_jpn'] is not None:
        return 'Japanese Title: ' + pprint.pformat(json_data['gmetadata'][0]['title_jpn'])

    if json_data['gmetadata'][0].get('title_jpn') is not None:
        return 'Japanese Title: ' + pprint.pformat(json_data['gmetadata'][0]['title_jpn'])


    if json_data['gmetadata'][0].get('title_jpn'):
        return 'Japanese Title: ' + pprint.pformat(json_data['gmetadata'][0]['title_jpn'])
```

Most of them give me Error: "Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly" because I expect the compiler is trying to convert strings. why is "is not None" not working for an empty json string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was not inside the method, but outside. You can't know because I didn't post this, but

```
await self.pm.clientWrap.send_message(self.name, message_object.channel, self.build_title_string(
                json_data) + "\n" + self.build_title_jpn_string(json_data) + "\n")
```

was producing the error. `build_title_jpn_string()` would return none but trying to concenate it with the string-title produced the error.

I fixed this by returning an empty string when the if was not hit.

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding how `in` works. `in` checks to see if a key exists in a dictionary, it does not index *into* a dictionary. That's what the square brackets do.

```
if 'title_jpn' in json_data['gmetadata'][0] is not "":
```

The above line will not evaluate as you expect.  It should be.

```
if json_data['gmetadata'][0]['title_jpn'] is not "":
```

This can be further simplified because empty strings `''` always evaluate to `False` in python. So instead of checking if the string is not empty, just check if it has any value at all like the following:

```
if json_data['gmetadata'][0]['title_jpn']:
```

If you're trying to guard against the fact that `title_jpn` might be optional and not always exist, you need to do two conditions in your if statement (which I think is what you were originally trying to do):

```
if 'title_jpn' in json_data['gmetadata'][0] and json_data['gmetadata'][0]['title_jpn']:
```

The above line first checks if the `title_jpn` key is present before trying to check if it's value is empty. This can be further simplified using the dictionary [`.get()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm) method which allows you to supply a default.

```
if json_data['gmetadata'][0].get('title_jpn', None):
```

The above will check if `title_jpn` is in the dictionary and return the value if it does, or `None` as a default if it does not. Since `None` is interpreted as `False` in python, the if block will not run, which is the desired behaviour.

> dict.get(key, default=None)

However, since `.get()` automatically sets the default value to `None`, you can simply do the following.

```
if json_data['gmetadata'][0].get('title_jpn'):
```

Comment: Is empty string coming from parsing guaranteed to be internalised? `is not ""` smells bad to me :(

Comment: @viraptor I've updated the answer to include an explanation of empty strings being falsey in python.

Comment: You were right but the error was located elsewhere for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Your .get won't work, since this applies to dictionaries. As far as I know, "In" won't work either since this is the syntax for a For loop. Probably you want the "[Find](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm)" method, since this matches a substring within a longer string (which is your goal, if I understand correctly). It'll return minus one if the string isn't found. So in your case, example use:

```
if json_data['gmetadata'][0].find('title_jpn') != -1:
```

Comment: Usually, ['gmetadata'][0]['title_jpn'] is a unicode string. Occasionally there is no name provided so the JSON-Value will be set to "". How can I check if the value is given?

Comment: I get "Error: 'dict' object has no attribute 'find'" when trying to use your code

Comment: @siryx sounds like you're using an older version of python that doesn't have the `.find()` method.

Comment: My python is 3.5 but I answered my question :)