# How can I check if JSON Value is empty in Powershell?

Tags: json, powershell

Dear Stackoverflow Community

I wanted to know if there is a way to do the exact same thing as here:
[checking if json value is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45134696/checking-if-json-value-is-empty)
but in Powershell.

For Example my JSON File looks like this:

```
{
    "Username":  "",
    "Password":  ""
}
```

Now I want to check if the value of Username (for example) is empty or not.

I am working with the newest version of Powershell. 
I have searched for a pretty long time and did not find anything, so I really hope you can help me.

Greetings

Martin

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I hope this is better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very easy in PowerShell, load the file, convert from Json check the value:

```
$myobject = Get-Content C:\temp\CheckEmpty.json | ConvertFrom-Json

if ($myobject.Username -eq "") {
    Write-Output "Username is empty"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!
But how would it look when I would want to check both Username and Password?

Greetings

Comment: @MartinSchmidt You need to put some more effort into this and at least try to understand. ;) If you read the code you should be able to understand how to do it.

Comment: Actually, I did find a solution. Kind of. I am now just checking if Username OR Password is empty. Still have not found a solution for AND OR yet